# Non www version of site not loading

Tags: loading

The non www version of my site is not loading.....i strongly think its DNS and not nginx(I haven't setup an redirect in nginx yet .The www version works perfect

I don't use any cpanel atm and i don't want to use one either 
I followed this tutorial 
http://www.broexperts.com/2012/03/linux-dns-bind-configuration-on-centos-6-2/
Its exactly like the one in tutorial above except that i modified his domain to mine
Here is my site 
http://www.leech4ever.com/ (Remove www from link and site won't load)

Please help me to solve this problem , i need both of the versions to work .I will redirect to version of my choice later
Some extra info:
OS - Centos 6 
No control panel 
Guys please help me to solve this non www version of site not loading.
Also the tutorial above don't say how to add slave nameserver(ns2).For me the ip of ns 1 is same as ns2.
Notice:
I am complete noob when it comes to dns , can you please give me setup by setup tutorial

Here are the dns configuration 
/etc/named.conf

> // // named.conf // // Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure
>   the ISC BIND named(8) DNS // server as a caching only nameserver (as a
>   localhost DNS resolver only). // // See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/
>   for example named configuration files. //
>
> options {     listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; };   listen-on-v6 port 53 {
>   ::1; };   directory   "/var/named";   dump-file
>     "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
>           statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
>           memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";     allow-query     { localhost; };     recursion yes;
>
> dnssec-enable yes;  dnssec-validation yes;  dnssec-lookaside auto;
>
> /* Path to ISC DLV key */   bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";
>
> managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic"; };
>
> logging {
>           channel default_debug {
>                   file "data/named.run";
>                   severity dynamic;
>           }; };
>
> zone "." IN {     type hint;  file "named.ca"; };
>
> zone "leech4ever.com" {
>           type master;
>           file "leech4ever.com.fwd"; };
>
> zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
>           type master;
>           file "leech4ever.com.rev"; }; include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones"; include "/etc/named.root.key";
>   leech4ever.com.fwd 
>   $ORIGIN leech4ever.com.
>
> $TTL 3D
>
> @       SOA     luna380.startdedicated.com.     root.leech4ever.com.
>   (12 4h 1h 1w 1h)
>
> @       IN      NS      luna380.startdedicated.com.
>
> luna380.startdedicated.com.     IN      A       85.25.100.52
>
> www                                     IN      A       85.25.100.52

leech4ever.com.rev

> $ORIGIN 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
>
> $TTL 3D
>
> @       SOA     luna380.startdedicated.com.     root.leech4ever.com.
>   (12 4h 1h $
>
> @       IN      NS      luna380.startdedicated.com.
>
> 211     IN      PTR     luna380.startdedicated.com.

Just a question
Accoding to me NS are ns6.nameserverservice.de. & ns5.nameserverservice.de then why hostname luna380.startdedicated.com. is in dns

You guys know better , please fix this for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe problem, as @Frederik Nielsen said, it's in the DNS. And, even if modify YOUR config, records aren't even pointing to your DNS Server. They point at `ns5.nameserverservice.de.`.
To start configuring your DNS server, just go [here](http://pgl.yoyo.org/as/hosts2bind.php) and it will generate the zone file.

PLus, when the name server at `ns5.nameserverservice.de.` was configured, you probably added the zone as `www.leech4ever.com`, because the domains `www.www.leech4ever.com` and `mail.www.leech4ever.com` exist! When you added the zone it should be named as `leech4ever.com`, without `www.` on it. Just see that you can access via `www.www.leech4ever.com`

Comment: You are right in all ways dude but when i add domain leech4ever.com (without www) it says domain already registered.So i have no option but to to put domain as www.leech4ever.com

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten to create a A record for @.

Check out these dig's for more info:
http://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=leech4ever.com%0D%0Awww.leech4ever.com&type=A&useresolver=8.8.4.4&ns=auth&nameservers=

Post your DNS configuration, so it can be investigated further.

Comment: Which file to edit to add the A record...Also please give an example

Comment: @Werulz According to your whois record, your DNS service is being handled by your hosting provider. You will need to use the tools provided by your hosting provider.

Comment: just added dns configuration.....its a dedicated server .My friend just added the suggested NS .We could have changed it to ns1.leech4ever.com but dns has been propagated already so useless to wait more time.Frederik must be right

Comment: @Werulz as user1460016 correctly states, you have to make the changes at nameserverservice.de as it doesn't look like you are fully in charge of the DNS setup yourself.

Comment: Guys i recheck the domain @ my PowerPanel..well my friend has put domain as www.leech4ever.com .I deleted that to put leech4ever.com , i get error Domain is already registered????wth is that happening.Its first time i am not using any control panel

Comment: @Werulz It seems like you are doing something wrong.. I would contact the place that hosts your DNS.

Comment: Fixed ........actually i had an old account with same provided but i lost pass of that account , so i created a new one.However domain was still in old account , that's why i was getting domain already configured message.After i added leech4ever.com as domain all got fixed

Comment: @Werulz If the answer by Frederik (or the other user) helped you solve the issue, you may want to consider selecting his answer as the right answer!